# Can I make a UIControl take ownership of "disposable" event targets?

Tags: iphone, ios, events

In my view controller I'm programmatically creating N buttons in my `UIView`. Each button needs to do something different, so I've made a custom handler class, which I create N instances of, each initialized with custom data. I create them in the body of a `for` loop and add them as targets, after which I don't need them anymore.

However, because `UIControl`s don't take ownership of their event targets, I need to hang on to these custom handlers myself (in the controller), introducing an extra ivar and the necessary release code. Is there a more elegant way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add those custom handlers to an NSArray that you retain in your controller (whatever controller is creating the buttons). Adding an object to an array retains it, so you will know that it is always around.

Comment: Likewise, releasing the array will release its contents as well.

Comment: I described this solution in my question; my question is actually: is there a more elegant way to do this? I guess not, then. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Thought you meant having an extra iVar for each of your custom handlers!

Comment: Ah, no, there is a variable number of them, so I don't know in advance how many handlers there will be. An NSArray is the only option then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)?